# Command line tool/library to edit Truetype font?

Tags: fonts, truetype

I'm building a game which uses Chinese/Korean/Japanese fonts. Those fonts, in TTF format, are very large for a mobile game(~8mb). I want to remove unused characters to reduce the size. 
I found [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) but it's an online tool, and what I want is a command line tool that can be added into my build script.

Is there such a tool? Or if I'm gonna make one, which library should I start from?

Comment: Have a look at Fontforge. It's a full featured font editor. But the best part: it can be build as Python extension.

Comment: Asking for tools is off-topic for SO. (But, off the record, you could take a look at Just von Rossum's [`ttx`](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools/), which act as an intermediate in XML.)